# JDBC: Issue with rendering Danish specific characters: Ø,Å,Æ

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

Problem:
Danish specific characters are displayed improperly(as non readable chars)

Given:
Database is `Microsoft SQL server 2019`, database collation is: `Danish_Greenlandic_100_CS_AS`. Data has been stored in Varchar column types, data has been already there; change collation or any data modification is not appropriate. I am not inserting data, only reading them(kind of report functionality).
Everything is working fine on my local machine, however on staging environment Danish characters are encoded improperly.

Connection initialization snippet

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put ("charSet", "UTF-8");
props.put("username", "dbusername");
props.put("password", "secret");
try (Connection con = getConnection(repositoryUrl, props);
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery)
) {
```

Reading data snippet:

```
ResultSet rs = //getResultSet
while (rs.next()) {
            Map<String, String> rowEntry = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (int i =0; i < columnCount; i++ ) {
                int columnIndex = i+1;
                String value = rs.getString(columnIndex);
                rowEntry.put(columnName, value);
            }
            result.add(rowEntry);
        }
```

Comment: My *guess* would be that the problem lies in what ever language you are using to insert the data, not the database (as inserting those characters when using that collation works fine). You should be tagging your application's language here too.

Comment: Thanks, nice point, application has been written in java. Data has been inserted by some other app, the user locale is da_DK

Comment: What OS do you use? What is the default character encoding? Both on the dev and production environment.

Comment: Dev Environment: I am using MacOS, SQL Server is installed as Docker Image.
Staging: app\SQL server is running on Windows. 
Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_275"

Comment: Does tempdb on the staging server also use Danish_Greenlandic_100_CS_AS?

Comment: Yep. Both databases uses same collation: 'Danish_Greenlandic_100_CS_AS'. On my local dev machine everything works fine, on staging server - 'Ø' 'Å' 'Æ'characters are encoded improperly(non readable chars)

Comment: If you try the same thing directly in the database, is it successfully writing the Danish characters?

Comment: Please, pay attention to the different default charsets of the JVM that you are using in MacOS (`UTF-8`) and Windows (`cp-1252`or some variant): I realized that you indicated charset `UTF-8` in you connection properties but maybe the problem is related with some kind of post processing (file output, ...)

Comment: I recommend to check locale of OS(in docker and on server),then the locale for the JVM, and server locale.

Comment: How are you testing that the characters are encoded improperly on the staging machine?  If you are just printing them to the command line, that could be your problem since Windows CMD uses `cp-1252` instead of `UTF-8` by default. If the machine is at least running Windows 7, run `chcp 65001` on the console before printing anything and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Disclaimers: I am not able to insert anything to the table, and alongside the issue with charset, the additional complication to this  is the fact that I have quite limited access to staging environment. @LajosArpad

Comment: Invalid characters are printed in web server response(which I assume is base64 encoded ) and in logs. I believe that when I invoke rs.getString (or new String(<input_raw_bytes>, "CharsetName)) then java is converting automatically to given encoding, and by default the result is UTF-8

Comment: @Nazar it's a key question to find out whether the raw query that is to be executed works. If yes, then it is something with your Java. If not, then it is something with your query.

Comment: @Nazar Both the server response and the logs are typical examples of the problem with the charset I tried to explain. Please, review the charset which is in place in the JVM in every environment. Please, review the value of the `file.encoding` system property in your laptop and in the staging environment, maybe it will provide you some insights into the problem.

Comment: Many thanks @jccampanero. You gave me good direction, i'll review those settings, I suspect that on windows based machine it won't be UTF-8. At least I have on option to try. 
What I have so far: I create a logs and in logs, when I opened them on staging(Windows 2012 Server RC2)/ or on Mac - I see issues, however If i specifically change encoding in logs file to ISO-8859-1 - logs looks good.

Comment: That is great @Nazar. I hope it works properly. If you think I can be of any help, please, tell me, I will be glad to help you if I can.

Comment: @jccampanero - I solved my issue and many thanks to your input. So please write the answer below so that I can accept it and gave your bounty. Story is following:. default JVM character encodings matters! I launched the same application with JVM parameter: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and it started working correctly. Without this option it picks `Charset.defaultCharset()` that is not UTF-8 for Windows case and it causes issues. Simply adding option `java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 <my_app.jar>` fixes the issue and the code from starts working correctly

Comment: It is nice @Nazar! I am very happy to know that you finally was able to solve the issue. I will post an answer summarizing the different comments. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you think that I can be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be related with the use of different charsets for the in MacOS (by default, `UTF-8`), in your local laptop, and Windows (`cp-1252` or some variant)  in the staging environment.

Although you indicated charset UTF-8 in you connection properties, perhaps the problem is related with some kind of post processing.

In fact, as indicated in the question comments, both the server response and log files are typical examples of the aforementioned problem with the charset.

Please, review the charset which is in place in the JVM in every environment: review and adapt if necessary the value of the `file.encoding` system property on your laptop and the staging environment, maybe it will give you some insights about the problem and help you solve it.

So in oder to fix your issue try to add `file.encoding` JVM parameter while running your application:

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar your_app.jar`