# Logging files names that contain Norwegian letters in the file name in Unix OS using a Jar executable

Tags: java, linux, unix, character-encoding, executable-jar

I have a simple java program that when run is supposed to traverse through the whole directory on a Unix server and log all files on the fileserver that contain Norwegian letters "å,ø,æ".

This is how it looks on the fileserver using winSCP:
[image]

In the end the logs.log file should look like this:

```
2022-10-25 14:27:02 INFO  Logger:99 - File: 'DN_Oppmålings.pdf'
2022-10-25 14:27:02 INFO  Logger:99 - File: 'Salg_av_gærden.pdf'
```

However, this is how it ends up in the log file, all Norwegian letters are represented with a square.
[image]

I can't seem to figure out why it happens. It probably has something to do with the encodings. Because when I run it on windows locally, everything runs as expected and I get the result I need. But when I build the project as an executable jar and run on the server it gets wrong.

Here is the code I am using.

```
public static void renameFiles3(File[] files) throws IOException {
    for (File filename : files) {
        if (filename.isDirectory()) {
            renameFiles3(filename.listFiles());
        } else {
            String fileNameString = filename.getName();
            if (fileNameString.contains("å") || fileNameString.contains("ø") || fileNameString.contains("æ")){
                logger.info("File: '" + filename.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        try {
            renamer.renameFiles3(files);
        } catch catch(IOException ex){
            logger.error(ex.toString());
        }
}
```

Someone pointed out that the encoding should be specified, but I am not sure how that is done. If I run "locale" command on the Unix server this is what I get as output.

```
[e1111111@ilt repository]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I use Putty to run the jar file. Here are the configs.
[image]

Stacktrace of the error I get when running the jar:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ./documentRepository/DN_Oppm�lings.pdf
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.move(UnixCopyFile.java:430)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.move(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:267)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1422)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:105)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:89)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:89)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:89)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:89)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:89)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.renameFiles2(Renamer.java:89)
    at com.example.fixfilenamesonfileserver.Renamer.main(Renamer.java:154)
```

What makes it even more strange, is that I can create for instance a folder with mkdir containing Norwegian letters in the name and it would be displayed correctly and also logged correctly if I create a file with Norwegian letters.

Comment: Your font lacks the necessary glyphs

Comment: Let's test that proposition. What does the following print? `echo -e '\u00F8'`

Comment: @g00se it prints this:  ▒

Comment: That's odd. You have an American Unicode locale that can't even print 'simple' Unicode chars.  What about `echo -e '\xf8'` ?

Comment: @g00se I must mention that I am using Putty to execute that command. I still get the same output : ▒.

Comment: Right, I'm glad you said. Can you paste Norwegian characters into the Putty terminal? You've got a 'wicked problem' here so you need to be *certain* that the font you're using in Putty can display these chars

Comment: Test them with another app like Notepad and then use that font in Putty

Comment: As Basil Bourque mentions, most likely the issue is in how you view the names in the log file. Edit this question with details of system property "file.encoding" in Win10 / Unix server [check settings for your logger, this may be cause] and what encodings are supported by the log file viewing app. On unix see what characters really are with `grep DN_Oppm logfile | od -xc` - don't rely on some display font of the app.

Comment: @g00se yes I can paste Norwegian characters in the putty terminal window. But if I run "ls -l" command I see that in the filenames Norwegian characters are substituted with a question mark (?)

Comment: So you suggest that the issue might be in Putty that is not able to recognize Norwegian characters and that affects the jar application as well ?

Comment: I also added my putty configs to the description.

Comment: That all looks OK. Do you have the utility `iconv` on that server? If not, it might help to install it

Comment: @g00se no I don't, how do you install something like this on the server?

Comment: Before that trouble is gone to. Change to that directory containing the pdf file starting "DN_" and run the following: `ls DN_* | sed -e 's#\xE5#\xc3\xa5#g' -e 's#\xE6#\xc3\xa6#g' -e 's#\xF8#\xc3\xb8#g'`

Comment: @g00se awesome,  that worked for most of the letters, except for capital Norwegian letters. Is there a way to incorporate this into the command I use to run the jar file? "java -jar FileServerRenamer.jar ./documentRepository"

Comment: Well tbh this is not really a Java question. Somehow, you've got filenames on there encoded as 'Latin1'. If I were in that position, the first thing I'd want to do is to change them to proper Unicode. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @g00se yes, is there a way to do that assuming I have thousands of files in that directory?

Comment: @g00se Also why is it that winSCP has no issues displaying those characters?

Comment: I can only assume that winSCP is actually doing some translating of encoding. `ls -N DN_*.pdf` is a command that I'd like you to run. The worst thing would be to start renaming files that were actually OK and only wrong when *viewed*  wrongly

Comment: @g00se "ls -N DN_*.pdf" this command still displayed Norwegian letters as "?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249156/discussion-between-g00se-and-vladyslav).

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717197/jdbc-issue-with-rendering-danish-specific-characters-%c3%98-%c3%85-%c3%86/65825163#65825163) for a very similar problem.

As stated in the aforementioned solution, the problem could be related with the use of different charsets in your local Windows laptop (probably, `cp-1252` or some variant) and your server.

As suggested, please, consider review the charset which is in place in the JVM in every environment, and review and adapt if necessary the value of the `file.encoding` system property on your laptop and the server environment, maybe it will help you solve the problem.

Probably running your jar with a proper value for the `file.encoding` JVM property may do the application work properly:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar your_app.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the charset encoding on the server to the one that is used for the filename and I got my jar to work.

Comment: Sorry @Vladyslav, after reading your question comments I realized I misunderstood this one. I am happy to see that you were able to make your jar work. Having said that, please, be careful when changing the OS charset encoding, it could have undesired effects in other programs and the OS itself, and sooner than later problems could arise: in my opinion, it is something inconceivable in a production system and in general in any modern OS. Did you try the  solution proposed in the answer or something similar? If not, please, try it: ultimately running a jar like this will isolate the charset ...

Comment: change to a single program, not the whole OS, and in this specific case probably will make your logs look as desired as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is no problem with your Java nor your file.

The problem is likely with the app you use to view that text. That app is using a font that lacks a glyph for those characters.

Edit your Question to note the app and OS if you want further assistance.

Comment: what do you mean by the app? the jar executable? @Basil Bourque

Comment: @Vladyslav You made a screenshot, of an app displaying text with squares. *That* app, the app that put that text on the screen.

Comment: I mentioned that I build a jar executable and run that on the server, the java code is in the description. OS on the server is Unix. Locally I use Windows 10. Is there anything else I should add? @Basil Bourque

Comment: Oh I think I got what you ment, I use Putty to view the files on the server and also to run the jar file

Comment: I can create a folder with Norwegian letters in the name using the same font, and that works fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are printing the letters to a terminal, the problem is most likely the terminal you use. If you are printing the characters to a terminal, make sure it is set to chcp65001, and a font that supports displaying norwegian letters fully. I have encountered similar problems while trying to display multilingual text due to the shortage of support for multiple languages in the same font.

So, to summarize, first set the terminal code-page encoding to chcp 65001, and then change the font of the terminal to a font that supports norwegian letter fully, and then run the jar file from the terminal like : `java -jar <jarname>.jar`